# Project Euler Problem #7 in Python (10001st prime number)

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, primes

I have managed to solve [the 7th Project Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7), however I think it can be improved by a lot, I am by no means a professional programmer or even consider myself really good at it. Any improvements / suggestions would be really helpful.

Problem statement:

> By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
>
> What is the 10 001st prime number?

This is my solution.

```
counter = 2
n = 10001
for i in range(3, 1000000, 2):
 k = 1
 while k < i:
  k += 2
  if i % k == 0:
   break
  if k + 2 == i:
   counter += 1
  if counter == n:
   print(i)
   raise ZeroDivisionError
```

The program does skip 2 and 3, in an attempt of mine to make it faster. At the end I raise an error in order to stop the program from looping.

Answer (score 4):

## Upper bound for p_n

There is a [known upper bound for the n-th prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270814/bounds-for-n-th-prime).

It means that you don't need to guess how large it could be. `upper_bound_for_p_n(10001)` tells us in less than a micro-second that the desired number cannot be larger than `114320`.

You just need to apply the [Sieve of Erathosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) up to 114320 and you're done:

```
from math import log, ceil

def find_primes(limit):
    nums = [True] * (limit + 1)
    nums[0] = nums[1] = False

    for (i, is_prime) in enumerate(nums):
        if is_prime:
            yield i
            for n in range(i * i, limit + 1, i):
                nums[n] = False

def upper_bound_for_p_n(n):
    if n < 6:
        return 100
    return ceil(n * (log(n) + log(log(n))))

def find_n_prime(n):
    primes = list(find_primes(upper_bound_for_p_n(n)))
    return primes[n - 1]
```

It calculates the *10001th* prime in 15ms on my computer, compared to 35s for your code.

Comment: Also, `1.26*n*log(n)` is a tighter upper bound for `n>17`

Answer (score 3):

What I dislike about your solution is the unnecessarily large amount of complexity your code has, which takes a toll on its performance.

When I solved this problem myself, I used the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to generate a list of prime numbers up to an arbitrary limit (I also picked one million, but you could [use a formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270814/bounds-for-n-th-prime) to compute it) and indexed that list at 10,000 to get the 10,001st number.

Here is how I implemented the sieve:

```
def primes_upto(limit):
    limitN = limit+1
    not_prime = set()
    primes = [2]

    for i in range(3, limitN, 2):
        if i in not_prime:
            continue

        for j in range(i*3, limitN, i*2):
            not_prime.add(j)

        primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

As you can see, this approach reduces the complexity of your code. Also, this is approximately 28 seconds quicker than your approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to pay attention to your algorithm, as Arnav is right there, but instead focus on style problems. It should be a giant red flag when you **raise a `ZeroDivisionError` when you aren't dividing by zero**. The correct solution here is to put your code inside a function, which will let you return the correct result. While here, you might as well make the upper limit of your range `n*n` instead of `1,000,000`, which will let it work for bigger values. Also, I know I said I wouldn't focus on the algorithm, but you can make the inner loop be `while k*k<i`, as any prime factor of `n` will be less than the `n**.5`. This simple change makes your code take .1 second instead of 30.

```
def nth_prime(n):
    counter = 2
    for i in range(3, n**2, 2):
        k = 1
        while k*k < i:
            k += 2
            if i % k == 0:
               break
        else:
            counter += 1
        if counter == n:
            return i

print(nth_prime(100001))
```

Comment: Nice. It's still pretty close to OP's code while not being too inefficient. You need `print(nth_prime(10001))`, though.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem and use memory efficiently is through generators, this way only one prime at the time is processed and you won't get out of memory

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n < 2:
        return False
    limit = int(n ** 0.5) + 1
    for i in range(3, limit, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def next_prime(count_limit):
    yield 2
    count = 1
    n = 3
    while True:
        if is_prime(n):
            yield n
            count += 1
            if count == count_limit:
                return
        n += 2

n = 10001

# Good
item = None
for item in next_prime(n):
    pass
print(item)

# Better
from collections import deque
dd = deque(next_prime(n), maxlen=1)
print(dd.pop())
```

Aditionally, if you need to run it several times, memoizing is suggested:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper

@memoize
def is_prime(n):
    ...
```

Comment: The first half of this isn't so much a review as an alternate method. You talk about reducing memory, but OP's algo was already `O(1)`

Comment: You could also use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to access the n-th element of your generator. You could also rename your functions. I wouldn't expect `next_prime` to return a generator of primes.